# An elegant way to write strip files of extensions on bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

Heres my bash script:

```
for next in `ls | grep -P -o "[a-zA-Z0-9]*" | grep -v "^c$" | grep -v "^obj$" | grep -v "^sh$"`
do
  mv "$next.c.obj" $next
done
```

As you can see, it is ugly. It basically removes the .c.obj extension from files (which, by the way, got there because I messed up the previous script). It does work, but it doesn't look look to be the most efficient solution.

The deed has already been done, so please don't post other ways to do it (rename or sed or awk).

I just want to know if this can be done using grep and bash only, but more elegantly.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: `filename="foobar.c.obj"; echo "${filename%*.c.obj}"`

Comment: `for file in *.c.obj ; do [[ -f ${file%.c.obj} ]] || mv "$file" "${file%.c.obj}" ; done`

Comment: Okay guys, this is exactly the kind of thing I wanted to see. You should add these as answers. @choroba  
${var%something} is interesting.